# What is the difference between target="_blank" and target="blank"?

Tags: html, hyperlink

Since I approached the web programming, to open a link in a new window I always used

```
target="blank"
```

but most of the time, here and in the rest of the web I have ever seen use:

```
target="_blank"
```

Both forms work (of course), but I do not know the difference between the two versions and they do not know what the correct way (and why)....

Comment: `_blank` is a keyword with special meaning where `blank` isn't. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`blank` targets an existing frame or window called "blank". A new window is created only if "blank" doesn't already exist.

`_blank` is a reserved name which targets a new, unnamed window.

Comment: Did you mean to say tab instead of window? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @MattGoldwater target=_blank is older than the concept of browser tabs. It usually opens a new tab nowadays.

Comment: @MattGoldwater Also, I don't think there's a requirement for browsers to have tabs. That's a convenience thing in the desktop paradigm, but afaik is largely done differently on mobile.

Comment: Let call former _valid navigable target name_ and latter  _navigable target keyword_.

Answer (score 33):

In short, use `target="_blank"` it always open a new window but use `target="blank"` it will open a new window at the first time and this window will be reused after the first.

Answer (score 11):

Both target="_blank" && target="blank" will open **new window or tab**.
The difference is

```
target="_blank"
```

On every click, it will open in a **new window**.

```
target="blank"
```

On another (Multiple) clicks, it will Open in the **same window** that opened for the first click (reuses the same tab).
*It reuses the same tab for all the linked documents with attribute ="blank"*

---