# Target="_blank" malfunction in hidden div

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a number of links inside a div that is shown onmouseover.  The problem I'm having is that the links are not opening a new tab every time a link is clicked.

This is a quick select area of our intranet and I want it to open a new link every time without regard to there being a tab of the linked website already open.  I'm not sure if the mouseover is the problem or not.

```
function show_content()
{

    document.getElementById('myDropdown').style.display = 'inline-block';

}

function hide_content()
{

    document.getElementById('myDropdown').style.display = 'none';

}

</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

    <div class="layoutcontainer">

        <div class="layoutleft">
        &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="layoutcolumns">

            <div class="dropdown-container">

                            <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn" name="dropbtn" onMouseenter="show_content()" onMouseleave="hide_content()">Quick Links</button><br />

                            <div class="dropdown">

                                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" onMouseenter="show_content()" onMouseleave="hide_content()">

                                    <a href="http://www.aba.com/default.htm" target="_blank">American Bankers Association</a>
                                    <a href="http://www.treasurydirect.gov/BC/SBCPrice/" target="_blank">Bond Pro Online</a>
                                    <a href="http://cedarrapids.iowaassessors.com/" target="_blank">Cedar Rapids Assessor</a>
```

Comment: `_blank` recycles tabs. you can move to a js-based "popup", which can be full-sized (aka a new tab).

Comment: You can do your hiding and showing with CSS, and leave out the Javascript. I would suggest looking into that approach

Comment: Have you tried target="blank"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703005/what-is-the-difference-between-target-blank-and-target-blank

Comment: When inserting your links into the html of this page they work just fine, also you should be doing the hiding and showing with css. not to mention you have your functions on 2 different elements. How does it make logical sense to have a `mouseLeave` on a button hides an element that's outside of the buttons element area?

Comment: To answer the question on why I'm not hiding/showing with CSS.  It's really kind of sad but I'm having to make this all work in IE5 standards due to reluctance on my companies part to update our intranet.  Everything is a huge pain.  I'm showing and hiding on the button and the div so that the mouse will open the div and stay open while the user mouses from the button to the div any other way and the div hides when you leave the button for the div and doesn't hide when they leave the div.  Truly annoying.

Comment: I'd be ok with making this work using Javascript Dandavis, do you happen to have a reference for me you'd recommend?